# Leaflet marker loses position after invalidateSize

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis

I have a Leaflet map that I resize to full screen when user clicks on provided icon and compress it to original size on second click.

I am using the `invalidateSize()` method after the resize is done but I have noticed that marker that I have on the map loses it's position.

[image]

---

The issue was that I was updating marker position on click and I think clicking on resize button caused the marker coordinates to be set to wrong position. So the leaflet works fine. I fixed it by using `event.stopPropagation()` on the enlargement icon instead of only `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

try set timeOut on that validate

```
 setTimeout(function(){map.invalidateSize()},500)
```

Comment: No success. I tried 250ms, 500ms and 1000ms. The pin just ended up in another place.

Comment: try removing the marker, and redraw again after invalidateSize, at least let me know the code

Comment: I could do that but in case there are more markers, it seems like very bad approach. I'd prefer proper solution instead of quickfix :)

Comment: very good approach for me is using D3  to draw a marker cos it draw a html element, not a bitmap, and using font awsome to make a marker, it just draw one word for each marker,but i will ensure you its not a quickfix